# How do I fix this UV problem?

Tags: uv

I added seams to this model and tried unwraping it, but this keeps happening and i cant figure out how to fix it. help please! [image]

Comment: Maybe you need to add seams? Also, what do you plan to do afterwards? Maybe another unwrap (like Smart UV Project) would work?

Comment: i tried smart uv project and adding more seams but its still a jumble of noodles. i figured out part of the problem. its all layered and i separated the islands, but now the vertices are so overlapped i cant tell how to separate them, and there are so many-

Comment: if you've correctly seamed it should be clean, also it depends on what you want to do next, if you plan to paint in the 3D view you can just unwrap with Smart UV Project and it should work fine, maybe tell a bit more about your project and maybe share your file

Comment: You might want to check if your object has inverted normals, doubled vertices or internal faces.